# Will "pkcon refresh" trigger something like "apt update" on Debian?

Tags: packagekit

I'm wondering if Packagekit's command

```
pkcon refresh
```

also pulls in information about updateable packages from Debian mirrors - like:

```
apt update
```

does - or if it just updates Packagekit's internal cache of avaible updates.

The man page just says

> Refresh the cached information about avaible updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `pkcon refresh` uses the underlying package management system, so on a Debian system it will refresh the APT indexes (like `apt update`).